Workflow dispatch variable also used for other triggers
I've a GitHub Actions workflow that starts the following way:
on: 
  schedule:
  - cron:  '0 0 * * 3'
  push:
    paths-ignore:
    - .devcontainer/**
  workflow_dispatch:
    inputs:
      buildConfiguration:
        description: 'Build configuration'
        required: true
        default: 'Release' 
        type: choice
        options:
        - Debug
        - Release

The variable I use the following way in the workflow:
- run: echo '${{inputs.buildConfiguration}}'

When the workflow is triggered through a push, the variable is empty. I fix it by setting a default value:
- name: Setup variables
  id: setupVars
  run: |
    if("${{inputs.buildConfiguration}}"){
      echo "buildConfiguration=${{inputs.buildConfiguration}}" | Out-File -FilePath $Env:GITHUB_OUTPUT -Encoding utf8 -Append
    }
    else{
      echo "buildConfiguration=Release" | Out-File -FilePath $Env:GITHUB_OUTPUT -Encoding utf8 -Append
    }

I was expecting this can be done more easily. Any thoughts?
